# How to punctuate a list of quoted questions

Tags: punctuation, quotes

I'm editing a work with the following passage, which describes seven signs:

> . . . signs. Each had both picture and words. The pictures were an X on a rock, a cave mouth, a castle, a big tent, a tall tree, flames, and an open mouth. The words, however, were disturbing questions: ‘Mayhem and madness?’, ‘Certain death?’, ‘Vicious wolves?’, ‘Acts of carnage?’, ‘Razor claws?’, ‘Broken bones?’ and ‘Running with scissors?’.

The single quotes contain the exact text appearing on each sign. Is the punctuation used for the list of sign texts acceptable (American usage), or is an alternative better?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if this answers your question, but here goes:

You could always have a character reading out the words aloud, which usually flows better. If you don't want to do that, I'm pretty sure your way works too.

Sorry if this didn't answer your question.